# What does the expression "till Saturday week" mean?

Tags: expressions

I'm a native speaker of American English.  But sometimes when reading a book by an English author or watching television shows broadcast on BBC I hear unusual (to my ears) expressions and am not entirely certain of the meaning.

I'm going to guess that the expression "till Saturday week" means "till Saturday a week from now".

A web search has brought up plenty of examples of this phrase being used, but I can't find anything that clarifies the meaning.

Comment: Cisatlantically we would say "until a week from Saturday".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "the Saturday after the nearest coming Saturday".

Answer (score 1):

Saturday week: Saturday (in a) week. A simple shortening.

English has a lot of shortenings of this type. Shortenings in language are so common and  important that they should be a chapter in any grammar, but I have never seen such a chapter. Our speed of thinking is rather fast, so in every language people try to get short ways of expressing themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Almost same end result as @d'alar'cop's answer,
it means "+1 week from today than the next Saturday".

It is the next Sunday that is a least 1 full week distant.
It is a bit unclear as to if you were saying it on Saturday it means the very next Saturday, or the Saturday after that. In those circumstances, one would normally say "next Saturday" or "Saturday 2 weeks from now.".

Comment: You mean "Saturday", right?  Not "Sunday".

Comment: Nope, Sunday! Tuesday would mean Friday, Wednesday - Monday.. no, you're right ;) you can also say "Saturday next" as opposed to "next Saturday" which is certainly more common, but sometimes confusion arises if it's Sunday - do we mean coming or coming after? Personally I'm an advocate of "this ~day" and "next ~day" exclusively, but of course, that only helps those to whom I speak...

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it means d'alar'cop that the expression means "the Saturday after the nearest coming Saturday".  This expression was still in common use in the southeastern United States in the 1970s.  While *this Saturday* means the the nearest-coming Saturday, the term *next Saturday* is ambiguous; it could mean the nearest-coming Saturday or the Saturday after that.  *Saturday week* clarifies.